# Using an HtmlHelper inside a custom HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Is there a way to do something *like* the following:

```
public static IHtmlString TableFor(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<MaterialGroup> groups, Func<HtmlHelper, MaterialGroup, int, string> tableContentsFunc)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("@Html.TextBoxFor(x => this.Model.Something)");
}
```

Obviously this is a trivial example, but when ever I try something of the sort it renders the Helpers i.e. `"@Html.TextBoxFor(x => this.Model.Something)"` as text on the page instead of processing them as helpers.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

```
public static MvcHtmlString TableFor(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<MaterialGroup>> helper, IEnumerable<MaterialGroup> groups, Func<HtmlHelper<MaterialGroup>, MaterialGroup, int, string> tableContentsFunc)
{
    String html = "<table class='materials joists'>";
    String endHtml = "</table>";

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); ++i)
    {
        HtmlHelper<MaterialGroup> groupHelper = new HtmlHelper<MaterialGroup>(helper.ViewContext, helper.ViewDataContainer); // Crashes here with cannot convert IEnumerable<MaterialGroup> to MaterialGroup.
        html += TbodyFor(groupHelper , groups.ElementAt(i), i);
        html += tableContentsFunc(groupHelper , groups.ElementAt(i), i);
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html + endHtml);
}

public static string TbodyForJoists(this HtmlHelper<MaterialGroup> helper, MaterialGroup group, int index)
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    MvcHtmlString markTextbox = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<MaterialGroup, String>(helper, x => group.Joists.ElementAt(i).Mark, new { Name = "MaterialGroups[" + index + "].Joists[" + i + "].Mark", Class = "auto-size first-column" });
    html += martTextbox;
    .
    .
    .
    return html;
}
```

When I attempt the above I get issues with the `HtmlHelper<>` Types.
If I leave it with just HtmlHelper I get an error telling me to explicity state since it doesn't know what I doing with it. If I explicitly state is have conversion? issues I guess you could say.

How can I simply just use the TextBoxFor in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Because that is very literally what you are telling it to do. The output of the helper itself is not processed by Razor. Whatever you return is what's going on the page.

However, you could always do:

```
MvcHtmlString textBox = Html.TextBoxFor(expression);
```

And, you'd have to feed the helper the expression to use. It perhaps would be easier in this situation to use `Html.TextBox` instead, but then you're going to have to do more work to try to figure out the right names and such for the fields.

It's going to be far easier and less convoluted to just use editor templates for this type of thing.

Comment: Updated question, not sure if it should be it's own but it's directly preventing me from doing your suggested solution, unless I'm miss understanding something here.